# Need a class that keeps track of how many different types of classes have been created

Tags: python, class

I have an *Animal* class defined as:

```
class Animal:
    counter = 0
     
    def __init__(self, species, sound):
        self.species=species
        self.sound=sound
        Animal.counter += 1
        
    def make_sound(self):
        return self.sound
    
    def number_of_your_species(self):
        return self.counter
```

I want *number_of_your_species* method to return how many different types of species have been created. The above code doesn´t work as it returns the TOTAL number that the class *Animal* has been instantiated.
In other words, I want the below to return 2 (cats) and 1 (dog):

```
tom = Animal("cat","miau")
pluto = Animal("dog","guau")
misifu = Animal("cat","miau")

tom.number_of_your_species()
pluto.number_of_your_species()
```

Comment: could you provide some broader context about your overall goals. Typically this flavor of meta programming isn't necessary (but sometimes it is)

Comment: Just keep a `set` of th `species` arguments. Generally though, making this a part of the constructor and an element of the class is not the greatest way of going about it

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Animal:
    counter = dict()
     
    def __init__(self, species, sound):
        self.species=species
        self.sound=sound
        if species not in Animal.counter:
            Animal.counter[species] = 0
        Animal.counter[species] += 1
        
    def make_sound(self):
        return self.sound
    
    def number_of_your_species(self):
        return Animal.counter[self.species]
```

Comment: Many thanks Ismail. This is exactly what I was trying, but with decorators instead within the class.